# 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign_centroids' in CLIMADA when using admin1

Tags: python, spyder, attributeerror

I am using CLIMADA which is a probabilistic natural catastrophe impact model for a project on tropical cyclone impacts in Florida. The following piece of code rises an AttributeError.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import netCDF4 as nc
import datetime as dt

# import CLIMADA modules:
from climada.util.constants import SYSTEM_DIR, DATA_DIR # loads default directory paths for data
from climada.engine import Impact
from climada.hazard import TCTracks, Centroids, TropCyclone
from climada.entity import IFTropCyclone, ImpactFuncSet
from climada.entity.exposures.litpop import LitPop
from climada.entity.exposures.litpop import exposure_set_admin1
import climada.util.plot as u_plot
from climada.util.scalebar_plot import scale_bar

# Initiate EXPOSURE:
exp = LitPop()
countries_list = ['USA']
state_list = ['Florida']
exp.set_country(countries_list, admin1_calc = True, res_arcsec=300, reference_year=2014)
exp.set_geometry_points()
exp.set_lat_lon()
exp.check()
exp['if_TC'] = 1
exposure_set_admin1(exp,res_arcsec=300)
exp = exp[exp['admin1'] == 'Florida']

# Initiate TC hazard from tracks and exposure
tc_hazard = TropCyclone()
tc_hazard.set_from_tracks(tracks, centroids=cent)
tc_hazard.check()

# Calculate TC impact from exposure and hazard and creat impact and impact function set (IFS)
# define impact function:
if_tc = IFTropCyclone()
if_tc.haz_type = 'TC'
if_tc.id = 1
if_tc.set_emanuel_usa(v_thresh=25.7, v_half=84.7, scale=1)
IFS = ImpactFuncSet()
IFS.append(if_tc)

# compute impact:
impact = Impact()
impact.calc(exp, IFS, tc_hazard, save_mat=True)
```

Calling the last line of the code yields:
AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign_centroids'

Can anyone solve the Error?

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e5655feac3c6> in <module>
      1 # compute impact:
      2 impact = Impact()
----> 3 impact.calc(exp, IFS, tc_hazard, save_mat=True)

~/Documents/WCR/CLIMADA_develop/climada_python/climada/engine/impact.py in calc(self, exposures, impact_funcs, hazard, save_mat)
    153         assign_haz = INDICATOR_CENTR + hazard.tag.haz_type
    154         if assign_haz not in exposures:
--> 155             exposures.assign_centroids(hazard)
    156         else:
    157             LOGGER.info('Exposures matching centroids found in %s', assign_haz)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/climada_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign_centroids'
```
````

Comment: post the complete error

Comment: AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'assign_centroids'

Comment: I added the complete error to the original question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs when you call the line `exp = exp[exp['admin1'] == 'Florida']`. This converts your Exposures object to a GeoPandas object. If you would run the `exp.check()` after this line it would fail.

The solution is to reconvert it back to an Exposures. As all the information is still included in exp this is easy

```
from climada.entity import Exposures
...
exp = exp[exp['admin1'] == 'Florida']
exp = Exposures(exp)
```

This is I think an effect of how inherited classes work in Python.